# Off-the-shelf Computer Software Depreciation

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, software, depreciation

For the 2018 tax year, I'm looking to take 100% bonus depreciation on software expenses for my US (California) based LLC. While the tax code states that "Off-the-shelf computer software" is eligible property for the section 179 deduction, it's vague on what "off-the-shelf" actually means. Does the definition include software purchased online? Are there cases where it might include subscription based software (where access is provided for 1 or more years)? Does it include web apps (that run in the browser as opposed to being downloaded to local storage)? Please help clarify this for me.

Comment: The close votes that are accumulating and labeling this a pure accounting  question are off the mark. This is a practical tax question about small business owned by the OP. Don't let the word "depreciation" fool you. I will refer you to the [these](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/are-small-business-questions-on-topic) [two](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/are-questions-about-single-person-family-businesses-on-topic-or-not) meta discussions about small business questions.

Comment: Agreed. I closed and reopened to clear the votes to close. In case we (mods) don't catch it, and it closes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In contracting Non-off-the-shelf software is software that has been modified or developed  for you. Microsoft office is off the shelf. Paying a company to develop an add-on to MS office would not be off-the-shelf.

How it is delivered isn't relevant. It could be purchased from a physical store, or delivered by the post office, or downloaded.

A subscription based model would be the same, though the payment frequency would be an issue. If you pay $x per month then only those months for this year would apply for this years taxes. If there is an annual or multi-year subscription it might have to be split the same way.

Comment: Look at subscriptions like rent. There's no depreciation there, just recurring costs.

Comment: @JanDoggen Your suggestion is that no type of off-the-shelf software is eligible for depreciation if it’s subscription based (regardless of the subscription duration)?

Comment: @JWK yes - because you don't buy a license, you _rent_ it. You cannot depreciate rent, you can deduct it.

Comment: If you're talking about taking a 179 deduction versus deducting rental cost, the net effect is the same: You deduct the full amount paid in the year that you paid it. Technically you should write it on a different line on the tax form, but as the effect on your taxes is the same, I'd be surprised if the IRS gave you a hard time if you did it wrong anyway. :-)